# Color entire row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have some script for coloring cells with duplicate values (many colors):

```
Sub DuplicateColoring()
    On Error Resume Next
    ' colors to change cells color
   Colors = Array(12900829, 15849925, 14408946, 14610923, 15986394, 14281213, 14277081, _
                   9944516, 14994616, 12040422, 12379352, 15921906, 14336204, 15261367, 14281213)

    Dim coll As New Collection, dupes As New Collection, _
        cols As New Collection, ra As Range, cell As Range, n&
    Err.Clear: Set ra = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Err Then Exit Sub

    ra.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' remember duplicates values in dupes
       Err.Clear: If Len(Trim(cell)) Then coll.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
        If Err Then dupes.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    For i& = 1 To dupes.Count ' fill cols with colors for different duplicates
       n = n Mod (UBound(Colors) + 1): cols.Add Colors(n), dupes(i): n = n + 1
    Next
    For Each cell In ra.Cells ' coloring cells
       cell.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want this script to color not only the cell, but the entire row. How I can do that?

Comment: replace cell.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value)) with cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))?

Comment: Posted it as answer, please accept it so that the question is marked as answered

Comment: How to do it? Just "Thanks", or some button? Sorry, I'm newbie.

Comment: Or, I understand. Marked it. Everything is OK? Thanks again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
cell.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
```

with

```
cell.EntireRow.Interior.color = cols(CStr(cell.Value))
```